# Which scripture describes six kalyana gunas (auspicious attributes) of Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, vedanta, vishishtadvaita, gunas

Vaishnav(ism) consider Vishnu as the supreme. I found that Vaishnav believes that Vishnu/Supreme has following six kalyana gunas (auspicious attributes):

[According to Vedanta Brahman has sat-chit-aanand nature but I think according to Vishishtadvaita Brahman possesses following six kalyana gunas]

- Jnana
- Bala
- Aishvarya
- Shakti
- Virya
- Tejas

So, I want to know which scripture describes these six auspicious attributes of Vishnu?

Comment: Do you want descriptions of the quality or only name of quality...?

Comment: @Tezz both if possible (I mean firstly I want to know which scripture say that Vishnu has these six kalyan gunas and secondly which scripture describe them)

Comment: Vishnu Purana states: "ऐश्वर्यस्य समग्रस्य धर्मस्य यशसरिश्रयः
ज्ञानवैराग्ययोश्चैव षण्णां भग इतीरणा ["

Comment: @Tezz Why don't you post it as answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Vishnu Purana** in 6.5.74 states:

> "ऐश्वर्यस्य समग्रस्य धर्मस्य यशसरिश्रयः। 
>   ज्ञानवैराग्ययोश्चैव षण्णां भग इतीरणा ।।" 
>  
>   **Complete splendor, virtue, glory, opulence, knowledge, dispassion - these six are known as bhaga.**

One who possess these Bhaga quality is known as Bhagavan. And the following verses after it identify **Bhagavan** as **Vãsudeva** or **Lord Vishnu.** Thus from this we can know Lord Vishnu Possesses six Auspicious qualities (Kalyana Guna). The same Paragraph continues stating:

> The purport of the letter va is that elemental spirit in which all beings exist, and which exists in all beings. And thus this great word **Bhagavan is the name of Vásudeva,** who is one with the supreme Brahma, and of no one else. This word therefore, which is the general denomination of an adorable object, is not used in reference to the supreme in a general, but a special signification. (Vishnu Purana 6.5)