# Esoteric meaning of bhagwan and bhakta

Tags: gods, bhakti, inner-meaning

In general, by calling "bhagwan", we refer God only and by "bhakta", we refer Devotees only. Is there any esoteric meaning to these terms which goes beyond general understanding? Does any scripture have these in details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although Aphorisms of  Narada Bhakti sutras define Bhakti, Bhakta is only known in perspective, of its summary -

> Narada says in Narada Bhakti sutra that Bhakti is supreme love of God.  God is the Indwelling Self of all living beings in this world. Thus love of God means love of all creatures, who are all His manifestations. **A Bhakta is thus one who does not separate religious and secular activities, but considers all of them as service of God.A person who looks upon every action, whether religious or secular, as worship of God will act without selfishness and will not harm others in any way**
> *[Sri. SN . Sastri](https://sanskritdocuments.org/sites/snsastri/index.html)(summary NaradaBhaktiSutras)*

**Gradation of Bhaktas according to Srimad Bhagavad Puran 9.2.45 -47**

> **Bhaagavatottama,** is: "He who sees himself in all creatures and all creatures in his own self. 
> The second category of devotees is: "He who cherishes love for the Lord, is friendly towards other devotees, compassionate towards the ignorant and does not harbour any enmity even towards those inimical to him".
> The last category of devotees is: "He who worships the Lord with faith in an image, but does not serve His devotees or other beings". 
> Prahlada says in the Bhagavata purana 7.10.4 that a person who worships God expecting some worldly benefit in return is not a devotee at all, but only a trader.
> *Sri. SN . Sastri*

**Four kinds of Bhaktas according to [BG 7.16](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=7&field_nsutra_value=16&etsiva=1&etadi=1) are** Artharthi(the self-interested),Jijnasu (the seeker after knowledge),Arti(the afflicted) Jnani(Wise)

**Definition of Bhakti according to Narada Bhakti Sutras**

> **sā tv asmin parama-prema-rūpā
>
> It is of the form of Supreme Love to
> wards God.**
> The term Bhakti comes from the root "Bhaj", which means "to be attached to God. " Bhajan, worship, Bhakti, Anurag, Prem, Priti are synonymous terms. Bhakti is love for love's sake. The devotee wants God and God alone. There is no selfish expectation here. There is no fear also. Therefore it is called "Parama-prema-rupaa. "
> **amṛta-svarūpā ca
>
> And it is of the nature of Nectar.**
> Devotion gives Immortality. Bhakti is an embodiment of Amritam or nectar. Nitya Sukha (eternal bliss), Immortality, Parama Santi (supreme peace), Nitya Tripti (eternal satisfaction), Akhanda Sukha (unbroken joy) can be had only in God
> [Swami Sivananda](https://www.sivanandaonline.org/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=1122)

**Bhagavan**
**_________**

Sri Shankaracharya in His commentary of Vishnu Sahasranama(60) and Bhagavad Gita, explains the term Bhagavan in accordance with Vishnu Purana 6.5.74 and 6.5.78

*Here Bhaga means opulence in completeness , and Van or Vat conforms (suffix known as matup prathyay) meaning the possessor. for eg..Dhanavan-possesor of dhana or wealth*

> **Bhagavan bhagahanandi   vanamali halaydhaha( Vishnu Sahasranama 60)**
>
> **aiśvaryasya samagrasya dharmasya yaśasariśrayaḥ
> jñānavairāgyayoścaiva ṣaṇṇāṃ bhaga itīraṇā [Vishnu Purana - 6.5.74]**
> Lordliness, prowess, fame, beauty, knowledge,non-attachment--the combination of all these six attributes is Bhaga. One who possesses these six attributes is Bhagavan.
>
> It is also said:
>
> **utpattiṃ pralayaṃ caiva bhūtānāmāgatiṃ gatim
> vettiṃ vidyāmavidyāṃ ca sa vācyo bhagavāniti [VishnuPuran- 6.5.78]**
>
> The origin, dissolution, the bondage and salvation of creatures, knowledge, ignorance-one who knows alI these is Bhagavān.
> *Sri Shankara commentary - Translation Swami Tapasyananda*

**Swami Sivanandas commentary on BG 10.14**

> Bhagavan is He? in whom ever exist the six attributes in their fullness? viz.? Jnana (wisdom)? Vairagya (dispassion)? Aisvarya (lordship)? Dharma (virtue)? Sri (wealth) and Bala (omnipotence). Also? He Who knows the origin? dissolution and the future of all beings and Who is omniscient? is called Bhagavan.Arjuna addresses the Lord as Keshava (Lord of all) because the Lord knows what is going on in his mind? as He is omniscient. As the Lord is the source of the gods? the demons and others? they cannot comprehend His manifestation or origin.

*VishnuPuran- 6.5.74 looks quite similar to the ref.  (cited in another answer) , Linga Purana I.70.98*

Comment: Well compiled answer. +1 If you can cover "bhagwan" part too..

Comment: add these in your answer body

Answer (score 5):

In the 17th chapter of the Kularnava Tantram, Lord Shiva gives interesting derivations of various terms and words that are widely found in Tantric scriptures.

The explanation as to why a Bhakta is thus called is mentioned as follows:

> BhajanAt parayA bhaktyA mano-vAk-kAya-karmabhihi |
> Taratyakhila-dukkhAni tasmAdbhakta itiritah ||
>
> Because by adoration (**bha**janAt), with supreme devotion, with his
> mind, speech, body and action, (**k**Ayakarmabhih), he crosses
> (**ta**rati) all miseries --- he is called *Bhakta*.
>
> **Chapter 17; verse 29**

And, for Bhagavan, there are already answers on this site that explain the various meanings of the word.

For example, in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18693/4732) by Tezz we find many such explanations

Comment: Thanks for Kaularnava reference.

Comment: Answer updated with the original verse @TheLittleNaruto

Answer (score 1):

I haven't come across any esoteric meaning of Bhakta. Bhagavan has been explained in many scripture. I am giving two examples.

**Bhagavan**

> **He is called Bhagavan (loveliness, excellence, fortune, glory).** He is
> called Siva because he is devoid of impurities. He is called Parama
> because he is distinguished and eminent. Since he protects, he is
> called Om.

**Linga Purana I.70.98**

> That which is imperceptible, undecaying, inconceivable, unborn,
> inexhaustible, indescribable; which has neither form, nor hands, nor
> feet; which is almighty, omnipresent, eternal; the cause of all
> things, and without cause; permeating all, itself unpenetrated, and
> from which all things proceed; that is the object which the wise
> behold, that is Brahma, that is the supreme state, that is the subject
> of contemplation to those who desire liberation, that is the thing
> spoken of by the Vedas, the infinitely subtile, supreme condition of
> Vishńu. That essence of the supreme is defined by the term Bhagavat:
> the word Bhagavat is the denomination of that primeval and eternal
> god: and he who fully understands the meaning of that expression, is
> possessed of holy wisdom, the sum and substance of the three Vedas.
> The word Bhagavat is a convenient form to be used in the adoration of
> that supreme being, to whom no term is applicable; and therefore
> Bhagavat expresses that supreme spirit, which is individual, almighty,
> and the cause of causes of all things. **The letter Bh implies the
> cherisher and supporter of the universe. By ga is understood the
> leader, impeller, or creator. The dissyllable Bhaga indicates the six
> properties, dominion, might, glory, splendour, wisdom, and dispassion.
> The purport of the letter va is that elemental spirit in which all
> beings exist, and which exists in all beings. And thus this great word
> Bhagavan is the name of Vásudeva, who is one with the supreme Brahma,
> and of no one else.** This word therefore, which is the general
> denomination of an adorable object, is not used in reference to the
> supreme in a general, but a special signification. When applied to any
> other (thing or person) it is used in its customary or general import.
> In the latter case it may purport one who knows the origin and end and
> revolutions of beings, and what is wisdom, what ignorance. In the
> former it denotes wisdom, energy, power, dominion, might, glory,
> without end, and without defect.

**Vishnu Purana VI.5**

Another explanation is given below.

> The word bhaga represents the group of six guṇas or blessed qualities:
> aiśvarya (lordship), dharma (righteousness), yaśas (renown), śrī
> (splendour), jñāna (knowledge) and vairāgya (detachment). One who
> possesses these in abundance is ‘Bhagavān.’ The term is generally
> applied to God; and even to sages and prophets. When applied to a
> goddess it becomes ‘Bhagavatī.’

**A Concise Encyclopedia of Hinduism by Swami Harshananda**

Comment: Not sure why not, but bhakti is one of the aspect which is much needed in the path of spirituality. And Hinduism not having any definition as such is hard to believe. Anyway thanks for the partial answer.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto the word esoteric means hidden meanings that is known to very few people. Bhakti means devotion and as pointed out in another answer has been discussed in Narada Bhakti Sutra and also in Sandilya Bhakti Sutra. I don't think either of these classic texts say anything that is not known to majority of people. This is the reason I wrote that I don't know of any esoteric meaning of Bhakta.